# View related products from product category and posted category

Tags: wordpress

I apologize for typing.
I've categorized a word in WordPress in the post category section
And I've made exactly the same thing in product categories
There is no plugin or code that automatically displays related product categories in the post?

Answer (score 0):

> WooCommerce - Show products from current product category (when
>   viewing a single product)

```
<?php
if ( is_singular('product') ) {
  global $post;
  // get categories
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
  $query_args = array( 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product', 'tax_query' => array( 
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $cats_array
    )));
  $r = new WP_Query($query_args);

  if ($r->have_posts()) {
    ?>
    <ul class="product_list_widget">
      <?php while ($r->have_posts()) : $r->the_post(); global $product; ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title() ? get_the_title() : get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('shop_thumbnail'); else echo '<img src="'. woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() .'" alt="Placeholder" width="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_thumbnail_image_width').'" height="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_thumbnail_image_height').'" />'; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?>
        </a> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
    wp_reset_query();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just copy it in single page